# Why should I ever use nonatomic in a property?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C properties: atomic vs nonatomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic)

By default all properties in Objective-C are atomic. If I need nonatomic I have to declare it. But I wonder why should I ever use nonatomic? Even if my applications are not multi threaded, atomic seems like the way to do it. What are the advantages of nonatomic?

Comment: @KennyTM: This is not a duplicate of your linked question.  That was asking what atomic/nonatomic means which is not the same as asking if you should ever use nonatomic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A short answer is performance. If you declare properties as `atomic`, the synthesized accessors will use locks to ensure that values are fully retrieved and set. If you don't need this, e.g., your application is single-threaded, you're incurring a performance penalty for those locks without getting a benefit.

Comment: And therefore setting properties to nonatomic without profiling counts as premature optimisation.

Comment: I am also intrested if this can really be significant for performance in common application to use this property, without nonatomic it is just more readable , one unused keyword free...